# What is the verifier in DotNetOpenAuth's DesktopConsumer ProcessUserAuthorization?

Tags: c#, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I am new to DotNetOpenAuth and I can't find what value to use as the verifier in ProcessUserAuthorization.

What I want to achieve is to log in with my user credentials into an application (called UserVoice) that uses OAuth. Here's what my code looks like:

```
string requestToken;
var authorizeUri = consumer.RequestUserAuthorization(new Dictionary<string, string>(), null, out requestToken).AbsoluteUri;
var verifier = "???";
var accessToken = consumer.ProcessUserAuthorization(requestToken, verifier).AccessToken;
consumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(endpoint, accessToken, data).GetResponse();
```

I tried to use my username, my password, my consumer key, my consumer secret, but nothing seems to work. Does someone know which value I should use as the verifier?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way to log in to UserVoice with DotNetOpenAuth. I think UserVoice's implementation of OAuth wasn't standard, but I was able to do it during this:

```
var consumer = new DesktopConsumer(this.GetInitialServiceDescription(), this._manager)
string requestToken;
consumer.RequestUserAuthorization(null, null, out requestToken);

// get authentication token
var extraParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "email", this._email },
    { "password", this._password },
    { "request_token", requestToken },
};

consumer = new DesktopConsumer(this.GetSecondaryServiceDescription(), this._manager);
consumer.RequestUserAuthorization(extraParameters, null, out requestToken);
```

Where GetInitialServiceDescription returns the good request description, and GetSecondaryServiceDescription is a hacked version and returns the authorize endpoint in place of the request token endpoint. The "request_token" returned this way (which is not really a normal request_token from my understanding of OAuth) can then be used as an access token for PrepareAuthorizedRequest.

Answer (score 0):

The verifier is the code that UserVoice would display onscreen after the user has said they want to authorize your app.  The user must copy and paste this verifier code from the web site back into your application's GUI, so that it can then pass it into the `ProcessUserAuthorization` method.

This is only required in OAuth 1.0a (not 1.0), and is there to mitigate certain exploitable attacks that were discovered in 1.0.  In your `ServiceProviderDescription` be sure you specify that the service is a 1.0a version (if in fact Uservoice supports that) so that DNOA will communicate to Uservoice that it should create a verifier code.

Incidentally, various tricks including scanning process titles or hosting the browser within your own app can eliminate the manual user copying the verify code step by having your app automatically copy it for him.

Answer (score 0):

The verifier is also used when the Authorization is done via WebAPI and you do not have a redirect displayed in a browser. In this you just send your AuthentificationRequest via code and get the verifier as a json-string without any user interaction.

In this case the process (for OAuth 1.0) looks as follows:

```
    public void AccessAPI ()
    {
        InMemoryOAuthTokenManager tokenManager = InMemoryOAuthTokenManager(YOUR_CLIENT_KEY, YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET);
        var consumer = new DesktopConsumer(GetAuthServerDescription(), tokenManager);

            // Get Request token
            string requestToken;
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters["email"] = "foo";
            parameters["password"] = "bar";
            Uri authorizationUrl = consumer.RequestUserAuthorization(null, parameters, out requestToken);

            // Authorize and get a verifier (No OAuth Header necessary for the API I wanted to access)
            var request = WebRequest.Create(authorizationUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "Get";
            request.Accept = "text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2";
            var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            string verifier = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().Split('=')[1]; //Irgendwie will Json nicht parsen

            // Use verifier to get the final AccessToken
            AuthorizedTokenResponse authorizationResponse = consumer.ProcessUserAuthorization(requestToken, verifier);
            string accessToken = authorizationResponse.AccessToken;

            // Access Ressources
            HttpDeliveryMethods resourceHttpMethod = HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest;
            var resourceEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint("https://api.discovergy.com/public/v1/meters", resourceHttpMethod);
            using (IncomingWebResponse resourceResponse = consumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequestAndSend(resourceEndpoint, accessToken))
            {
                string result = resourceResponse.GetResponseReader().ReadToEnd();
                dynamic content = JObject.Parse(result);
            }
    }

    private ServiceProviderDescription GetAuthServerDescription()
    {
        var authServerDescription = new ServiceProviderDescription();
        authServerDescription.RequestTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(YOUR_REQUEST_ENDPOINT, HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest);
        authServerDescription.UserAuthorizationEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT, HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest);
        authServerDescription.AccessTokenEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(YOUR_TOKEN_ENDPOINT, HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest);
        authServerDescription.ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V10;
        authServerDescription.TamperProtectionElements = new ITamperProtectionChannelBindingElement[] { new HmacSha1SigningBindingElement() };
        return authServerDescription;
    }
```